# Script para verificar se diretório está vazio

Tags: php, linux, bash, sistema-de-arquivos

estou batendo cabeça para criar esse script.

Preciso de um script, pode ser em bash ou php mesmo, que verifique se um diretório possui algum arquivo dentro, que não seja um outro diretório.

Esse diretório que tenho de varrer é em servidor linux que tenho aqui na empresa, então o script pode ser em bash, que eu coloco pra executar diariamente no linux. Ou então em PHP, que faço o linux executar o arquivo PHP, sem problemas tb.

Alguém sabe como fazer?

Comment: Já tentou `ls /path/to | wc -l` ??

Comment: Vou testar aqui Valdeir, mas pelo que li aqui acho que já me ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em php pode ser feito assim de acordo com a Resposta encontrada em : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684881/php-how-to-list-files-in-a-directory-without-listing-subdirectories

```
$files = scandir($dir); 
foreach($files as $file){
    if(is_file($dir.$file)){
      ....
```

Ele usa scandir para recuperar todo o conteudo da pastar($dir) e em seguida usa is_file para veridicar item por item se algum deles é um arquivo

Comment: Obrigado Ari, essa deu certinho.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar [alias](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/Criando-aliases-uteis).

#### Encontrar diretórios vazio (ShellScript):

```
 alias searchDirEmpty='dirEmpty() { find $1 -type d -empty -print; }; dirEmpty'
```

Como usar: **searchDirEmpty */path/to***

#### Verifica se um determinado diretório está vazio (ShellScript):

```
alias checkDirEmpty='checkDir() { [[ $(ls $1 | wc -l) == 0 ]] && echo "Diretório vázio"; }; checkDir'
```

Como usar: **checkDirEmpty */path/to***